# Comparision of acidic strength of benzoic and peroxy benzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Out of the two which one is stronger  acid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benzoic acid is 10<sup>3.7</sup> times stronger:

peroxybenzoic acid pK<sub>A</sub> = 7.9 [ref 1]

benzoic acid pK<sub>A</sub> = 4.2 [ref 2]

**References**:

[1]:  Ullmann's Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry, 5th ed. Vol. A19, Wiley, p. 206

[2]: Harris, Daniel (2010). Quantitative Chemical Analysis (8 ed.). New York: W. H. Freeman and Company. pp. AP12.